# VTT(Subtitles) is not working from external url

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webvtt

I am trying to play the subtitle of a movie from an external url but it doesn't work and when I try to add vtt file whcih is loacally stored then it works. Below are the codes
`<video id="video" controls preload="metadata">
   <source src="video/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="http://devcache.filmflexmovies.com/Test/Movies/2016/6/28/SDFEATUREMOVIE/Creed ENG.VTT" default>
</video>`
Above code doesn't work. But when I copied the content of vtt it works.
`<video id="video" controls preload="metadata">
   <source src="video/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="abc.VTT" default>
</video>`
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are being blocked by a crossorigin access issue. To access VTT files from a different domain, you must satisfy two conditions:

1. Add the right CORS headers to the site *hosting* the [VTT file](http://devcache.filmflexmovies.com/Test/Movies/2016/6/28/SDFEATUREMOVIE/Creed%20ENG.VTT). You may not have access to this site, but thankfully it looks like right header is already being used: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.
2. Add the crossorigin="anonymous" attribute to your pages's audio/video element. Something like this:

```html
<video id="video" crossorigin="anonymous" autoplay controls preload="metadata">
  <source src="video/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="http://devcache.filmflexmovies.com/Test/Movies/2016/6/28/SDFEATUREMOVIE/Creed ENG.VTT" default/>
</video>
```

I hope this works for you.